# How to make a contiguous vector of bools in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, std

How do I make a contiguous vector of `bool` quantities in C++? I read many warning against using `std::vector<bool>` and I would like to store a mask to a `std::vector<double>`.

To make my purpose a bit more clear, I would like to apply statistics on my `std::vector<double>` for those elements in the `bool` vector that are true. In order to do that at maximum performance, I would like the vector to be contiguous.

Comment: Why not just a ``std::vector<char>`? And I didn't understand the mask part.

Comment: It is for data analysis purposes: with mask I mark elements that should be excluded. I want a mask that is contiguous in memory for performance reasons.

Comment: @rodrigo `vector<bool>` is implemented very differently than `vector<char>`. 8 elements of `vector<bool>` occupies 1 byte while 8 elements of `vector<char>` occupies 8 bytes.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `std::vector<bool` _per se_. The issue is that the boolean values are packed, one bool per bit, so you cannot get pointers or references to the values. If you don't mind, you can even get advantage of it.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo: I know, and that's why it is generally discouraged: because they are not actually standard containers, strictly speaking. If you need a standard container of bools, `std::vector<char>` can fit the bill. If you just need an indexed array of booleans, `std::vector<bool>` may be just right.

Comment: Do you want contiguous bit bools or contiguous byte bools?

Comment: I want to pass it into a function where I do a statistical operation on all elements in a `std::vector<double>` where an element of a bool vector is `true` at the same index.

Comment: You could always declare a `std::vector<unsigned char>` with `size = std::ciel(boolVecSize / 8.0)` (where `boolVecSize` is the size your `std::vector<bool>` would have had had we used it) and do manual bit manipulation.

Comment: @R_Kapp That sounds complex for storing bools.

Comment: @Chiel: Indeed it is, but if it's absolutely necessary to ensure that the `bool`s are contiguous, then it's the only way I can think of that doesn't involve memory overhead. You can always write a simple wrapper class that would make the accesses easier, as well.

Comment: sorry if this is late but why not std::vector<int> 0 or 1?

Comment: @FirstStep it is a huge array and I would like to minimize memory usage

Comment: If you want to minimize memory usage just use `std::vector<bool>` and ignore the popular warnings.

Comment: bench `vector<bool>` against `vector<char>`. If your access pattern is sequential `vector<bool>` performs quite well.

Comment: I don't understand why somebody votes this down, I think it is a legitimate question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know what are specific issues people find problematic with `std::vector<bool>`, as they do not neccessarily applicable in your case. Probably the most important of those is that it is not neccessarily contiguous. And here *contigous* is probably a misnomer. The memory allocated for the whole vector is still likely to be in contiguos chunks, however, `&vec[0] + i` will not be the same as `&vec[i]`.

However, a lot of other `std::vector` qualities still stand - it still provides for constant time random access, for example.

Bottom line - do not simply be afraid, instead, understand what the implications are.

Comment: What do you mean with that the data actually is contiguous?

Comment: @Chiel, I mean that such a vector is still going to provide constant time random access. And the only way to achieve that is by storing your packed booleans as contiguous memory. As a result, it is still going to be cache-friendly.

Comment: @Chiel Understand, then profile, profile, profile. That and nuking the site from orbit are the only ways to be sure.

Comment: @SergeyA: Actually, that logic is flawed. `std::deque<bool>` also has O(1) random access and it's certainly not contiguous. (But it is piecewise contiguous)

Comment: @MSalters, I agree, piecewise contiguous is a better term.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::bitset`
The class emulates an array of bool elements, but optimized for space allocation
Cited from: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/

Comment: The size of a `std::bitset` must be know at compile time.  If the OP is using a vector they may not know the size which would mean they could not use a `std::bitset`.

Comment: Well, you also can write a walk around optimization using a vector of known size bitsets

Comment: @Chiel You are correct.  There is nothing in the standard that says it is contiguous or even an container.